# XNA Sprite Visibility

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

Just wanted to check if this was the correct way of going about this or if there is a better way to do it. I have created a button which toggles on and off when clicked. I want to make this so that when the button is on, a sprite is visible, when it's off, it's not. Am I correct in thinking you'd set the sprite to null and then re draw it when on or should it be done in another way?

Thanks in advance.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just keep track of the visibility with a bool:

```
private bool _displaySprite;  // Class-level field
```

Then, when your button is clicked it toggles that bool:

```
private void Button_Clicked()
{
    _displaySprite = !_displaySprite;
}
```

And then you just check the bool in your Draw function:

```
private void Draw()
{
    if (_displaySprite)
    {
        // Draw the sprite
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go down a slightly different route.

I would use *something like*

```
 class Sprite
 {
    public bool Visible {get; set; }
    public Texture2D Texture{get; set; }
    public Vector2 {get; set;
 }
```

If you wanted to expand this further (and you probably should), you could add draw/update methods to this class, make it abstract and have all your game objects inherit from it. You'll have more control over the state of your sprites, and it will likely tidyup your code.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.Xna.Framework.DrawableGameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.aspx) is meant to participate in both the Update and Draw loop providing an implementation for IUpdateable and [IDrawable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.idrawable.aspx).

Depending on how your "sprite" objects are coded, you may be able to simply set DrawableGameComponent.Visible.